# Cannot delete from table with join in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sql-delete

I have this query, BadCustomerIDQuery, that returns a list of CustomerIDs to delete from a separate table, CustomerIDTable.

However I can't get it to work without errors such as "Could not delete specified table" or "Specify the table containing records you want to delete"

Attempt:

```
DELETE CustomerIDTable.*
FROM CustomerIDTable
INNER JOIN BadCustomerIDQuery ON BadCustomerIDQuery.CustomerID = CustomerIDTable.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM CustomerIDTable
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM BadCustomerIDQuery)
```

Comment: It does not take much time (<1s) to open either CustomerID table or the BadCustomerIDQuery (the table has 4k records, and the query right now has 1 record, so it should be asking me to delete 1 row) and yet it takes forever to run this; is there a faster way to do the same thing?

Comment: Is `CustomerID` an index? To tell, open the table in design view and locate the field. At the bottom in Field Properties is `Indexed` selected as *Yes* or *No*? Try running as *Yes*.